# Parallax zoom out effect issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax, zooming

I am experimenting with parallax and attempting to get a nice zoom out on scroll, However I am struggling with the image becoming smaller than the browser width and the height of the `div`.

As you can see in my example the red background of the wrapper section is visible as you scroll down.

You can view the example at www.adamkhourydesign.com/test

HTML

```
<header id="header_container">
    <div class="header_back"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
#header_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 85, 0.5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 800px;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/name.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.header_back {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(../img/header_bg.jpg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery

```
var pContainerHeight = $('#header_container').height();

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var wZoomIn = 1+(wScroll*.0005);
  var wZoomOut = 1-(wScroll*.00005);

  if (wScroll <= pContainerHeight) { 
    $('.header_back').css({
      'transform' : 'scale('+ wZoomOut +')'
    });
    $('.logo').css({
      'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /0.7 +'%)'
    });
  }
```

Comment: You set `transform: scale()`, so obviously it scales, making it smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Arnell Balance, with the answer you posted I managed to tweak my code slightly to get it working.

I moved the background image out of the Background property and added it as an image inside the div. Then in css I made the image eg 140% width and height auto. and finally offset the left margin half of the amount that is over 100% in this case -20%.

Code looks like this now:

**HTML**

```
    <header id="header_container">
            <div class="header_back">
                <img src="img/header_bg.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="logo"></div>
   </header>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var pContainerHeight = $('#header_container').height();

$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var wZoomIn = 1+(wScroll*.0005);
  var wZoomOut = 1-(wScroll*.0005);

  if (wScroll <= pContainerHeight) { 
    $('.header_back img').css({
      'transform' : 'scale('+ wZoomOut +')'
    });
    $('.logo').css({
      'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll /0.7 +'%)'
    });
  }
```

**CSS**

```
#header_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 85, 0.5);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 800px;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/name.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.header_back {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(154, 100, 85, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header_back img {
  height: auto;
  width: 140%;
  margin-left: -20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code, I was able to get a smooth parallax zoom out on scroll, but using the `background-size` property instead of `transform: scale()`. I did it by initially zooming in the background image a little (e.g. `105%`) and then gradually zooming it back out to `100%` as you scroll down. I also made sure that the `background-size` will not go below `100%` so that it keeps covering the whole header area.

**CSS**

```
...
.header__back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url("http://www.adamkhourydesign.com/test/img/header_bg.jpg") top center no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: 105%; /** the initial zoom **/
    overflow: hidden;
}
...
```

**Javascript**

```
var height = $('#header_container').height();
var logo = $('.logo');
var background = $('.header__back');

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    logo.css('transform', 'translateY(' + scroll / 0.7 + '%)');

    var backgroundSize = 105 - (5 - (height - scroll) / height * 5);
    backgroundSize = backgroundSize < 100 ? 100 : backgroundSize;
    background.css('background-size', backgroundSize + '%');
});
```

Check out this fiddle to see it in action: [parallax zoom out demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8tay1jb2/)